# How to fix Blazor/Razor warning: Unexpected character sequence in property value

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In our Blazor-App we want to apply the width of an htmle-element by the `style`-attribute and an binding:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: @Progress%;"></div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int Progress { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem**: Visual Studio shows me an warning: "Unexpected character sequence in property value"

[image]

This warning has no CL... or BL... code.

**Question**: What is an elegant way to fix this warning?

Answer (score 8):

I found a possible solution now, based on Henk Holterman´s answer which not shows the warning any more:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: @($"{Progress}%");"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Blazor sometimes needs a little help to find the C#/HTML border. `@(...)` usually does the trick.

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: @(Progress)%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the warning still appears.